# Azure B2C custom policy failed to read/write to a custom attribute

Tags: azure, attributes, policy

I created a custom attribute: termsofservice. I can read and update it through Graph API explorer (beta version). I also can output the claim to tokens. However, when hooking it up with a custom policy the user journey cannot read nor persist the value. Here are the relevant policy changes in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml. Thanks for any suggestions!

```
  <ClaimType Id="extension_termsofservice">
    <DisplayName>Terms of use</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>User acceptance of Terms of Service</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
  </ClaimType>
......


<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ClientId">[my app client id]</Item>
        <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">[my app object id]</Item>
      </Metadata>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles> 
</ClaimsProvider>
......


    <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-Consent">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>     
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsofservice" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="granted" />
      </PersistedClaims>           
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsofservice" />
      </OutputClaims>          
      
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />       
    </TechnicalProfile>
......
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PromptUserTermsOfUse">
      <DisplayName>Finthrive Terms of Use</DisplayName>
      <Description>It prompts new users who has not accepted the terms of use yet</Description>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.termsofuse</Item>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_termsofservice" DefaultValue="granted" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Consent" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
......

     <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>extension_termsofservice</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="ConsentPrompt" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PromptUserTermsOfUse" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: I tested to include the custom claim: extension_termsofservice into the sign-up step, by modifying the technical profile: LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail, and AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail. It can save!

Comment: After experiments, I realize my approach has a shortfall. It used SelfAssertedAttributeProvider for its technical profile: PromptUserTermsOfUse, but put the inner profile: SM-Consent as UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement, instead of ValidationTechnicalProfile. After fix, I also feel the SelfAssertedAttributeProvider is specifically for user sign-up, where a user needs to provide an email and go through email validation. This is too heavy for my purpose. I am wondering if there is another provider, that takes the signed-in username as input and allows me to persist a custom claim value.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this example](https://justidm.wordpress.com/2018/10/01/add-a-terms-of-use-consent-page-to-azure-ad-b2c-user-journey-with-custom-policies/) and followed it: . The key info I found is that I need to extend two technical profiles: *AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress* and *AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId*. I also simplified my other technical profiles according to this example. After that, my problem is solved. By the way, I extended the two profiles in TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml instead of in the base. Great example, thanks Peter!

Comment: documentation and examples around custom polices are so low. Thanks for the link. These should be basic scenarios with documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the example. In my case, I needed to add my new persisted claim in the Technical Profile UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId.